# Style guide rules for multi-word command line arguments?

Tags: command-line-interface

Does anyone know of any command line interface style guides with rules about how to present multi-word options?

There are many varieties possible.

Many programs, like `grep`, use a two-hyphen prefix and a hyphen separator. For example:

```
--byte-offset
```

Some programs, like `find`, use a one-hyphen prefix and an underscore separator. For example:

```
-ignore_readdir_race
```

Some programs, like `java`, use a one-hyphen prefix and a colon separator. For example:

```
-verbose:gc
```

A few programs, use a two-hyphen prefix and an underscore separator. I haven't yet found a common example of this but my company has internal utilities that use this style. For example:

```
--save_only
```

Some programs even support multiple varieties.

[GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/) and [The Art of Unix Usability](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taouu/taouu.html) are great references but I don't see information about multi-word options specifically.

I'm looking for links to command line interface style guides that specifically address multi-word options. I don't care what rules or advice these guides offer as long as they mention multi-word options.

Comment: Nature abhors underscores. Just sayin'

Answer (score 6):

GNU recommends using hyphen separators for multiword arguments, as in `--byte-offset`

You may find the libc manual and its chapter concerning [Program Argument Syntax Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) useful. The fragment relevant to your question is:

> GNU adds long options to these conventions. Long options consist of
> ‘--’ followed by a name made of alphanumeric characters and dashes.
> Option names are typically one to three words long, with hyphens to
> separate words. Users can abbreviate the option names as long as the
> abbreviations are unique.